# React / Как добавить в массив несколько значений input через один onChange?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [example, setExample] = useState([]);
```

Есть n-е количество input, которые я создаю кнопкой с одним и тем же onChange.

Пытаюсь собрать в массив следующим образом:

```
const handleChange = name => event => {
    setExample([...example,{ [name]: event.target.value }])
};
```

Обработчик вешаю ни инпуты вида:

```
<input type='text'
       className='input'
       name={"некое уникальное имя"}
       onChange={handleChange("некое уникальное имя")}
/>
```

но в массив попадает весь ввод, т.е. ввожу "123.123" и попадает {name:123}, {name: 123.123}, ...
Как верно это реализовать?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: добавьте код где Вы вешаете обработчик на onChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setExample(st=>({ ...st, [name]: event.target.value }))`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.